# Trusted Platform Module (TPM) connection type

Tags: connector, motherboard

What connector is a discrete, pluggable Trusted Platform Module (TPM) supposed to use? I've seen LPC (Low Pin Count) mentioned, but I am not sure. Or do TPMs support multiple types of connectors?

Comment: " I've seen LPC mentioned". What is "LPC"?

Comment: @DavideAndrea LPC bus is Low Pin Count bus. Commonly used (or was) between motherboard chips for slow old legacy IO.

Comment: @Justme. Thank you, I edited the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Motherboards have simple pin headers for the module.

Different buses are used. The module must have same bus as the motherboard. Some use LPC, some use SPI. Even if same bus is used, pinouts may be incompatible.

Often the pin header connectors have different size, different number of pins, or missing/keyed pins to prevent connecting incompatible devices together.

Comment: Are these pin headers specially intended for a TPM or are they general purpose? If they are specific for TPMs, then the likelihood of being able to use a TPM in a motherboard goes down.

Comment: @Melab TPM headers are for TPMs. What general purpose use would you expect from a TPM header and why? Also, if you have a TPM header on a motherboard, why would the likelyhood of being to use a TPM on a motherboard go down? To me, having a TPM header on a motherboard means you are sure to plug in a TPM and use it.

Answer (score 1):

[An unshrouded right-angle, 2-row, 2 mm pitch, 14 or 20 circuit, female PCB header](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=unshrouded_fem_headers_2) (my site) such as [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adam-tech/2RS2R-20-G/9833065) but with a plugged position for keying.

See: [Trusted Platform Module (TPM) versions 1.2 vs 2.0 and header number of pins](https://serverfault.com/questions/927761/trusted-platform-module-tpm-versions-1-2-vs-2-0-and-header-number-of-pins)

Comment: What is "keyring"? I don't understand the first link. Is that what TPMs use?